# Find the initial position of the lowest/longest sequence in an array

Tags: python, python-3.6

Similar to sleep cycles alarms, I need to cut my array in the best place possible (low numbers in my scenario) respecting a range of min/max amount of values...

To simplify, if I am able to find the longest lowest sequence in an array, I think I can move forward.

For example:

`[1,2,3,0,1,4,5,6,6,0.1,1.1,2,4]`

Should return 9, because 0.1 is the first value of the longest lowest, even though I have a lower value than 0.1;

`[4,5,7,10,0.13,0.2,0.12,8,9,28,0.1,0.11,0.102]`

Should return 10, because it is lower than 1, even though, the sequence has the same amount of numbers...

Longer sequences (in my scenario) are more important than lower. Any idea how to start this? I don't have a threshold, but a solution involving this should be ok I think (if calculated on-the-fly)

Comment: When you say "longer sequences", do you mean that a particular value is repeated sequentially in the array (i.e. 55 is the "longer sequence" in this array [44, 44, 55, 55, 55])?

Comment: No, longer because the amount of "low numbers" is higher than other sequences of "low numbers"

Comment: I could do something like, get the average, or the first quartile and everything that is below that is a "low number"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your convoluted logic behind "longest lowest", but this could be a good start:

```
data = [4,5,7,10,0.13,0.2,0.12,8,9,28,0.1,0.11,0.102]

result = [[0,0]]
threshold = 1.0
for num, val in enumerate(data) :
    if val < threshold :
        if result[-1][1] == 0 :   # start a new sequence
            result[-1][0] = num
            result[-1][1] = 1
        else :                    # continue existing sequence
            result[-1][1] += 1
    else :    # end the previous sequence
        if result[-1][1] > 0 :
            result.append([0,0])
```

returns (first element, sequence length) pairs:

```
[[4, 3], [10, 3]]
```

that you may further analyse for the length, value of the first element or whatever you like.

Comment: Nice to add to the confusing by using `num` as the sequence index and `i` as the value of the array element.

Comment: @rioV8 got easier to understand now ?

Comment: still confusing because `num` and `val` mean the same thing. `i`, `j`, `k` are by convention used as indices. `for i, val in enumerate(data) :` would be clearer. You never see, hopefully, `for (int num=0; num<array.size(); ++num) { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks, I think that a solution without the threshold would not be possible right?

Comment: @Gabrielle what are we looking for without a threshold?

Comment: @lenik My idea is to get the longest lowest, which means the longest sequence with the lowest numbers in the array... the priority is the length

Comment: @lenik I think that the closest I can get of what I want is to get the average from the array and use it as the threshold and apply your solution...

Comment: @Gabrielle how do you define "the lowest" ?

Comment: @lenik this is really trick, in the ideal scenario the longest sequence would be with the lowest number for example `[0,0.1,0.2,0.3,6,7,8]` but then, I would not have a condition to stop, since 6 is still, a lowest number than 8...

Comment: I will get the average, and then, everything below the average is considered "lowest"

Comment: @Gabrielle `mean` might work better than `average`, because you're not going to be thrown off by extreme outliers.

Comment: @lenik Are you talking about the `median`? Because `mean` and `average` would be the same, right?

Comment: @Gabrielle right! my fingers are way ahead of my thinking =)